# Persist expired session data into new session in express js

Tags: node.js, session

```
const adminSession = session({
  secret: process.env.ADMIN_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: sessionStore,
  name: "adminSession",
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 600000,
    secure: false,
  },
});
app.use(adminSession());
app.get("/sessionViews", function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++;
    res.send(`Number of view: ${req.session.vies}`);
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1;
    res.send(" No views");
  }
});
```

Here after the session is expired, `req.session.views` value is also gone. And new session will be  generated with `req.session.views`=0. 
That's how we create the number of views in the certain page, isn't it? 
How to keep value persistent with another session?

Comment: well that is kind of the point of sessions. The information about the session is gone when the session expires. If you want to persist data, maybe look for a database?

Comment: So the number of views for the certain page functionality would be created using db not  sessions?
here is the question that I have been waiting for answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122281/express-session-expiry-vs-first-time-loging-in.
It is also related with sessions. if you can help with this. I would be very helpful